# Show only unique values from Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array in php:

```
array(12) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(17) "Kungsvägen 118 A "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1969-06-17"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1969-06-17"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1980-05-22"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(12) "Myntvägen 8 "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1980-05-22"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1993-05-09"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1989-06-28"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1991-03-17"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1989-10-30"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(23) "Gasslanda VÄSTERGÅRD 2 "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1980-10-30"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1980-10-30"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(14) "Skolgatan 1 B "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1990-05-01"
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adress"]=>
    string(11) "Ågatan 6 A "
    ["dob"]=>
    string(10) "1990-05-01"
  }
}
```

I want to print out the unique adress-values in this array when I'm doing an foreach. As you can see, `Skolgatan 1 B` appears several times in the array, so I want to print it out just once in my loop. How can I do this? I have tried

```
array_unique([$newArray['adress']);
```

but that does not work.

Comment: Well, you can alternatively save what you have printed, and if it's already printed, skip printing in the foreach :)

Comment: How did you end up with this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$printed_vals = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item['adress'], $printed_vals)) {
        print_r($item);
        $printed_vals[] = $item['adress'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$unique = array();
foreach($array as $item)
    $unique[$item['adress']] = $item;
```

Then use `$unique`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have solved this problem. Hope it helps.

```
$non_duplicates = array();
$i=0;
foreach( $addresses AS $address ){
    if( !in_array( $address['adress'], $non_duplicates ) ){
        // Use one of the below array_push statements
        array_push( $non_duplicates, $i ); // if you want to get the array key position
        array_push( $non_duplicates, $address['adress'] ); // if you only want a new array of unique addresses
    }
    $i++;
}
```

If you have chosen to only return key positions to $non_duplicates yo can then retrieve your unique positions from you array by:

```
foreach( $non_duplicates AS $key ){
    echo $addresses[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to print address once but dob in multiple times.. in that case you can do something like followings

```
$printed_vals = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $printed_vals[$item['adress']][] = $item['dob'];
}

foreach ($printed_vals as $address => $values) {
    echo $address . " => " . implode(",", $values);
}
```